# How to use flags with Steam browser protocol?

Tags: steam

I am current launching my games using : `steam://run/<gameid>`

I also want to use **-silent** flag with the above mentioned protocol.

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947

Or any other method to launch steam silently in the background and launch the game.

Other stores who do this, do it this way : `com.epicgames.launcher://apps/<appname>?action=launch&silent=true`

Comment: Go back to your other question, up vote the answers that were helpful and click on the checkbox near the answer that helped you solve the problem. If you do these things you'll help keep Stackoverflow organized and will make the life of future visitors a lot easier. Do this and I'll come back here to help you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@start /min "" "D:\steam\steam.exe" -login user123 qwerty456 -nofriendsui -slient -appid 570940`

for run `Dark Souls REMASTERED`

you can't use `steam://` with `steam.exe` command-line options